# Object Spy using Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, web, jscript

I am working on a project in Java where I should be able to launch a site and then recognize a browser Web Elements with a Mouse Over, like the Object Spy in QTP. The Elements that I hope to get are Name, Class Name, ID, Tagname, Linktext,Partial LinkText, CSS Xpath..etc..

I am kind of lost on how to bridge the Browser and the Application.Can anyone help?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a javascript/Jquery code into the web page to capture element properties. You can pass the element back to Java class and catch it in a `org.w3c.dom.HTMLElement` object. Using the methods in the object, you can retrieve all the attributes corresponding to the `Element`.

Comment: I am still a bit lost on how exactly I will launch all website and then inject a Javascript/Jquery code into it.Can you show me a sample code that works ?

Comment: You must be able to get access to web engine object of the browser. Then if you do webEngine.executeScript("window"); it will inject the javascript code into the browser. I did this into my JavaFX browser. You might have to do some research on other browsers.